# Trying to fetch the first record from a group in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, apache-spark-sql, greatest-n-per-group, min

I'm trying to query the earliest timestamp for a candidate, for a project, for a contract on spark SQL.

```
spark.sql(
      """
        |SELECT
        | DISTICT
        | timestamp,
        | candidate_id,
        | project_id,
        | contract_id
        |FROM candidatesHistory
        |GROUP BY timestamp, candidate_id, project_id, contract_id
        |ORDER BY timestamp DESC
        |LIMIT 1
        |""".stripMargin)
```

This code doesn't do it, it just fetches one record - how do I get the oldest timestamp for a candidate for a project for a contract?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have 4 columns in the table, then you can use aggregation:

```
select candidate_id, project_id, contract_id, min(timestamp) first_timestamp
from candidateshistory
group by candidate_id, project_id, contract_id
```

If there are more columns and you want to bring all of them, then you can use `row_number()` to *filter* the table:

```
select ch.*
from (
    select ch.*,
        row_number() over(partition by candidate_id, project_id, contract_id order by timestamp) rn
    from candidateshistory ch
) ch
where rn = 1
```

For each `(candidate_id, project_id, contract_id)` tuple, this gives you the row with the earliest `timestamp`.

Comment: I don't want the latest, I want the earliest, which is why I'm ordering by DESC.

Comment: @TannishaHill: that's an easy fixed to the query. Done. Note that, as opposed to what you seem to think, a descending ordering puts the latest first (which actually mislead me).

Answer (score 0):

This should work, though don't know if it's the best way:

```
SELECT candidate_id
, project_id
, contract_id
, timestamp
FROM (
    SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY candidate_id ORDER BY timestamp) AS RNK
    , candidate_id
    , project_id
    , contract_id
    FROM candidatesHistory
    ) as CH
WHERE CH.RNK = 1;
```